# How to write condition in XML for Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have an XML file in a Red Hat server.

The file has a condition tag, so when I make the condition having (in) to insert more than one value, the file is translated as the following:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM CRM_PUBLISHSITE_CSM 
WHERE coresiteid IN ('CI00052378'' , ''CI00032667'' , ''MS10011314'
```

The problem is that when I put a single quote before or after a comma, it's duplicated (written twice). Also, the ")" is not written after a single quote.

**The xml file:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataload>
        <object>
                <group>SITE</group>
                <name>SITE</name>
                <table>CRM_PUBLISHSITE_CSM</table>
                <condition>coresiteid in ('CI00052378' , 'CI00032667' , 'MS10011314') </condition>
                <instance-name></instance-name>
                <mod-level></mod-level>
                <javaclassmapping>com.equant.dataload.action.PublishSiteImpl</javaclassmapping>
                <attribute-list></attribute-list>
        </object>
</dataload>
```

Comment: hi, can you explain little further on 
how you are appending the single quotes after you fetch the where condition from the xml ?

Comment: well, you can try as below
replace(v1,chr(39)||chr(39),chr(39));
where v1 being the whole "where" condition which you get from xml

Comment: "the file is translated" - how? What is doing the translating? We can't see what that is doing or how/why it's deciding it needs to escape those single-quotes. If you have code that is doing that translation incorrectly then you need to show us that code so we can help you find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `''` is an escaped `'`. Oracle defines strings with `'`, so if it sees two together it knows that it's actually just one that is in the string.

eg:

`select 'A dog''s life' from dual` returns `A dog's life`

`select 'A dog's life' from dual` returns an error

You need to look at how the returned string is to be used to determine how to place your escaped quotes.